# Android how to draw a path in a specific area (like a coloringbook) only?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, path, draw

I'm banging my head around with drawing a path/lines in an specific area only. 
For example i got an image with a butterfly (just white with black border). I just want to paint inside the image (only on the white area).

The image is scalable and will be shown on the screen inside a drawingview.

My idea was, to detect the pixel's color during the ACTION_MOVE - Event and then set the alpha of the paint to 0, if the color isn't white. But the line isn't going transparent if I paint over the border.

Here's my code:

```
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);


        if (fill) {
        } else {
            if (!ausmalen) {
                //Standard
                if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;
                    circlePath.reset();
                    circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, circle_radius, Path.Direction.CW);
                }
            } else {
                //Bestimmen der Farben der Pixel für evtl Füllen der View etc
                try{
                    int pixel = mBitmap.getPixel((int) mX, (int) mY);
                if (pixel == Color.WHITE) {
                        mPaint.setAlpha(255);
                        System.out.println("white at " + mX + " " + mY);

                        System.out.println("mX= "+mX+" m>= "+mY+" x= "+x+" y= "+y);
                        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                        mX = x;
                        hX = x;
                        mY = y;
                        hY = y;
                        circlePath.reset();
                        circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, circle_radius, Path.Direction.CW);
                        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);                     
                } else {
                    mPath.reset();
                    mPath.moveTo(mX, mY);
                    System.out.println("nicht weiß!!!!!!");
                    mPaint.setAlpha(0);
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                    mX = x;
                    hX = x;
                    mY = y;
                    hY = y;
                    circlePath.reset();
                    circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, circle_radius, Path.Direction.CW);
                    System.out.println("hX= " + hX + " hY= " + hY + " mX= " + mX + " mY= " + mY + " stroke= " + mPaint.getStrokeWidth());
                    int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
                    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                    System.out.println("r= " + redValue + " b= " + blueValue + " g= " + greenValue + " a= " + alpha);
                    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            };}
            dv_bg.invalidate();
            dv_bg.refreshDrawableState();
            dv.invalidate();
            dv.refreshDrawableState();
            setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        }
```

Every help is appreciated. Maybe there is also a better way to achieve this. Thx a lot.

Comment: What are the bounds of the image? Is this a viewgroup or your image? Please narrow down your question. also look at `canvas.clipRect()`

Comment: Isn't clipRect only for a rectangle? How would this help if your image is curvy? Did i missunderstood the way how cliprect works?

Comment: do you mean like a coloring book?

Comment: yes, like a coloring book sounds good.

Comment: What about EdgeDetection and then clippath it? May that work?